# AWS Nvme Failure Rate

Tags: amazon-web-services

Currently looking at some of our options as to performant database options inside AWS (RDS being too slow even with provisioned IOPS) looking for some data as to the failure rates of their NVME drives (or at least a guesstimate). Wondering if anyone has come across some AFRs for these drives so I can know what to expect in terms of failure chance.

Comment: You are almsot certainly more likely to lose your drive to maintenance activity requiring an instance stop or retirement, or to other host hardware failure.  Storing a primary database on emphemeral disks is definitely not the way to go.